# Color difference atan and atan2 difference in results

Tags: android, algorithm, math, colors, color-space

EDIT: obviously I've made ann error in `atan2` after many different approaches, but still curious to find formulas.

I've read multiple topics and articles, yet do not understand why atan and atan2 give different results after convertion into degrees. Here is my example (*from CIElab colour space*) `x -79.7751, y 2.677374209`. Calculation without any changes to code will give incorrect value in both cases:

```
atan(-79.7751 / 2.677374209) = -1,537 / or in degrees -88,07778762
atan2(-79.7751 , 2.677374209) = 3,1258 / or in degrees 179,0965
```

However, that example is from an [article](http://www2.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/ciede2000/ciede2000noteCRNA.pdf) so we can check results. Basically answer should be `271.9222`. I've found over the internet correction for `atan`, now I've got same results, yet I still have indeterminate value for `x=y=0` in `atan`, hence some corrections should be made for `atan2`. Unfortunately I did not found any that would yield same result and and would be proven (*I mean what could be found in literature*). Most sources for CIElab say to use `atan2` **without any corrections** and as you can below it is not correct in my particular case. Here is what I got on this:

```
atan(-79.7751 / 2.677374209) = -1,537 / for atan < 0 : atan + 2pi
hence atan = 4,7459 / or in degrees 271,922 ( BINGO! )

atan2(-79.7751 , 2.677374209) =  ̶3̶,̶1̶2̶5̶8̶  3,108 / or in degrees  ̶1̶7̶9̶,̶0̶9̶6̶5̶  178,0777876
now convert, for deg > 90 : 450 - deg
atan2 result 271,922
```

̶A̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶,̶ ̶*̶c̶l̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶c̶i̶g̶a̶r̶*̶.̶ ̶A̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶1̶ ̶d̶e̶g̶r̶e̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶.̶ My question is how exactly I can make a correction of `atan2` to get proper results?

Comment: How did you obtain 3.1258 for `atan2`? Was that the error you made (because Javascript says it is also -1.537)? If so what are you still looking for?

Comment: What language and math library are you using? Some libraries swap the two parameters of `atan2()`. Btw, `-88.07°` represents the same angle as `271.92°`. So, both values are correct.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I was using excel `atan2(x,y)` to test it before going java

Comment: @NicoSchertler well, now after swapping values I got correct answer, thank you!. Oh boy, this is so dumb, sorry! Would never think about it. How do I pick your answer as a solution?

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us. You can't accept a comment as an answer. And since it was just a typo, I would recommend just to delete the question.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it." /sigh. If any mod will see it, please delete.

Comment: Accepting Ripi's answer is also fine :). After all, he also suggested to swap the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas may be wrong, depending on the library you use. See the C++ std for [atan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan)  and [atan2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2):

atan(y/x) returns in range {-pi/2, pi/2}

atan2(y,x) returns in range {0, 2pi}

You have exchanged `x,y` in both cases. This has the effect of this figure:
[image]

Comment: Solved. `atan` was fine, `atan2` exchanged. Thank you.

Comment: Sure? `atan` is for `y/x` and you use `x/y`

Comment: @Ripi2 Depends on what angle you want. More precisely, the tangent is defined as the quotient of opposite side and adjacent side. In many cases, they map to `y` and `x`.

Comment: result fits an article and follows multiple wikipedia formulas, so I guess that how it should be in excel in particular